# Filtering numbers from a variable list in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a script that pulls stock numbers off a website for me. I've been able to find the element on the page using BeautifulSoup, but I haven't been able to convert the output of that variable into just a number. I've tried turning the data in the variable into a list and then using `split_list =[i.split() for i in numbers]` and then further filtering by `no_integers = [token for token in tokens if not token.isdigit()]`, all which I found on stack overflow btw. I'm an absolute beginner and any help is really appreciated. Here's the code and output

```py
def requeststock():
    response = requests.get(baselnk)
    soup = bs(response.content, "html.parser")
    find_element = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"page-main__emphasis"})
    correct_element = [d.text.encode('utf-8') for d in find_element]
```

This is what this so far returns

`[b'Boosted XR Battery', b'88']`

I want just that integer at the end to return from the function. Thanks!!

**Edit: I fixed it.... but I have no clue how. Here is my solution.**

```py
def requeststock():
    response = requests.get(baselnk)
    soup = bs(response.content, "html.parser")
    for wrapper in soup.find_all('span', {"class":"page-main__emphasis"}):
        numero = wrapper.text
    return numero
```

The internet is a magical thing.

Comment: You know how to access a value in a list I assume. The "integer" is a `bytes` object. Decode it to a string and use `int` to create an integer out of the string. Then return the integer. Example: `return int([b'Boosted XR Battery', b'88'][1].decode())`

Comment: what's the website?

Comment: @QHarr boostedusa.com

Comment: @Matthias I am having trouble decoding into a string. I replaced where you said ```[b'Boosted XR Battery', b'88']``` to my variable ```correct_element``` because the number that it pulls will vary. But it's throwing an error. I've tried many other solutions from google but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Is there a page I have to navigate to from boostedusa.com to view the stock you are trying to scrape?

Comment: @QHarr https://boostedusa.com/cart/31537621631087:1234 

I solved my problem tho, updated my question if you want to look at my new code and explain to me why it works because I am actually clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: I fixed it.... but I have no clue how. Here is my solution.**

```py
def requeststock():
    response = requests.get(baselnk)
    soup = bs(response.content, "html.parser")
    for wrapper in soup.find_all('span', {"class":"page-main__emphasis"}):
        numero = wrapper.text
    return numero
```

The internet is a magical thing.

Answer (score 0):

Little confused by your question. I think you're close though. Here is a short example that should help you filter better.

```
>>> mylist = [b'Boosted XR Battery', b'88']
>>> [i for i in mylist if i.isdigit()]
[b'88']
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove the brackets, the "b" and the apostrophes? Just to get the raw number. That's what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: That will show why the b occurs. To remove the [] s you want to lookup python list index for good explanations of how to access items in a list

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty drawn out but simple solution:

```
var = [b'Boosted XR Battery', b'88']
var = [i for i in var if i.isdigit()]
var = str(var).replace('b', '')
var = var.replace('[', '')
var = var.replace(']', '')
var = var.replace("'", '')

print(int(var)) # 88
```

There's definitely a better way to do this, but this is by far the most simple/easy to understand.

Comment: Relying on the representation of a list with different objects? Really? And what happens if we don't have a "Boosted XR Battery", but [4711](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4711) with the list `[b'4711', b'89']`?

Comment: @Matthias Then you do the same thing, but handle it slightly differently. It's simple enough and works for this question.

Comment: I suggested using the standard way: getting the second element with the list index and converting that valuer to an integer with `int`. NOT string manipulation of a string that is used for debugging. If I want something that works for this question I could just do `print(88)`.